# How can i blend a container with two different containers in css

Tags: html, css, mix-blend-mode

I have a container and I want to apply the mix-blend-mode: difference to it to blend with its parental container and the parental container of the parental container (and so on). When I apply the blend-mode the container only blends with its parental container. How can I achieve the result that I described earlier.

The code structure is like this:

```css
.sec1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
}
.sec2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: white;
}
.svg1 {
  position: fixed;
  ...
}
```

```html
<section class="sec1">
  <section class="sec2">
    <svg class="svg1" ...>
      <text ... style="...;mix-blend-mode:difference;"></text>
    </svg>
  </section>
</section>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: no code , no chocolate, maybe this something like this ? https://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/grOEGp

Comment: @G-Cyr I think the code doesn't clarify it  more in this case, when you read the comment I wrote under Astrit's answer. The code you linked to does only blend the Label with the body -> only one element. This works for me too,  but as I wrote I want to blend it with multiple objects...

Comment: multiple objects, okay, but what is the layout/structure/css/background colors ? it can be anything where mix-blend-mode could be efficient or not at all. there is no way that we can guess what you really have. If you believe your comment important, add it to the question. What is obvious to you is to you for sure ;)

Comment: @G-Cyr Ok i have edited the post

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want exactly to achieve since this is not quite clear. 
I would suggest you to read tutorials like this from [Codrops](https://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/mix-blend-mode/)

Otherwise when using the mix-blend-mode results can depend on color and other factors but you can also stack to a point for e.g you can make a class and apply that blend mode. 
Check this basic example below.

```css
body {
  background: gray;
}

.blend {
  mix-blend-mode: exclusion;

  font: caption;
  padding: 2rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: aqua;
}

aside {
  background-color: beige;
}

a {
  background-color: green;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<main class="blend"> 
<p>This is main container </p>

<aside class="blend"> 
This is the sidebar 
<a href="#" class="blend"> Link </a> 
</aside>

</main>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To precise my question: This is how it looks now [link](https://ibb.co/7yTD6vR). The svg only blends with the div2 but not with the div1. This is the hierarchy: <div1><div2><svg></div2></div1>. How can I achieve to blend the svg with both containers, so that the svg is white over the black container and black over the white container. The mix-blend-mode is set inside of the svg in the properties of the <text> tag.

Answer (score 0):

luckily, it seems that you are using black and white colors, so you can expect `mix-blend-mode` to do the job .

a font filled with white, and a black background should also blend on your  white background

example

```css
.sec1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
}

.sec2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: white;
}

.svg1 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0; 
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  transform:translatey(-50%);
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="sec1">
  <section class="sec2">
    <svg class="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="115" width="25">
  <text x="2" y="-2" transform="rotate(90 0,0)" fill="white" style="font-size:25px">Some text</text>
</svg>
  </section>
</section>
```